# I'm looking for a good introductory book/paper (or any study material) on delay differential equations

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, delay-differential-equations

I need some recommendations for a good introductory (undergrad or grad) book on delay differential equations. If there is a paper or lecture notes that you think would be good to start from, please feel free to share.

Comment: Chapter 2 of Hale and Lunel, "Introduction to Functional Differential Equations" shows how to generalize the existence/uniqueness theorem for ODE (Cauchy-Lipschitz Theorem) to delay differential equations.

Answer (score 0):

The book "An Introduction to Delay Differential Equations with Applications to the Life Sciences" written by Hal Smith is a graduate level textbook on DDEs. The book "Delay Differential Equations: With Applications in Population Dynamics" written by Yang Kuang is another option, which is longer (in terms of the number of pages) compared to the previous books. The emphasis of both books are DDEs with applications on mathematical biology (since both mathematicians are famous for their work on this area of applied mathematics).